# Android_Install failed version downgrade

Tags: android, version, upgrade, google-play, downgrade

I'm going to update my apk on **GooglePlay** Store and I know that i have to upgrade the version code and name in manifest file however, it made install_failed.

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE
```

Please check logcat output for more details. Launch canceled!

I modified the version code and name like this: **android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.0.5"**

Did i make it wrong?

Answer (score 48):

Just uninstall the application on your device first and then install the fresh one.

Comment: Perfect. You made my day. Thanks

Comment: This will erase any configuration i have in my application. I preffer use `adb install -d -r your.apk` as said @kemuri.

Answer (score 44):

When you are  installing via `adb` you can pass `-d` to allow version downgrade

```
adb install -d -r your.apk
```

`-r` will also replace the existing app

Comment: Since Android 7 (Nougat), [for security reasons](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/921dd75), `adb install -d` no longer works unless the package is marked as debuggable.

Answer (score 9):

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE Please check logcat output for more details. Launch canceled!
```

I solved it by using the command prompt,navigating to project folder >adb uninstall package (you can get the package from Manifest.xml file).

In my case :
D:\projectFolder\AndriodApp>adb uninstall com.example.app

Again launch the App in emulator or mobile.

Answer (score 5):

just use this:

`$ adb -e uninstall your.application.package.name`

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: This command executes an uninstall on a running emulator instance. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This sped up my db migration testing by a factor of 2! Thank you

Comment: You should drop the `-e` flag when not using an emulator.

Comment: Sometimes a device restart is also required after doing this.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the `versionCode` of your currently installed version of the application is greater than 2, thus resulting in a failed installation on the device.

Comment: I made the version code to "105" however i got a dialog "Error, please restart application error code : 20 " on my device. I can't find error on Logcat. Do you have any idea with it? I have no clue.

Answer (score 4):

This happen when your installed apk version less than version by which you are trying to build apk. For example you just upgrade your version and try to build apk with it but you already a installed apk in your device which was build by the previous one.

In this case you must uninstall the previous apk and build a new one with the exiting version.

Answer (score 3):

I just disabled it first in setting>apps>allapps>app and I was able to install using regular command:
adb -r name.apk

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to do is check versionCode and versionName for palystore apk and then increment number by one for both versionCode and versionName.

for instance:in playstore  `versionCode="42"`and `versionName="1.4.2"` then change it `versionCode="43"` and `versionName="1.4.3"` in your latest code

Comment: Great, but exactly *where* is that versionCode to be found?

Comment: 1)Programmatically by manifest file to increment versions.
2)Earlier versions in production go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470402/query-the-google-play-store-for-the-version-of-an-app

Answer (score 1):

Ajay Takur is correct. Your App's current version code should be greater than the playstore one.

But do refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808599/android-emulator-installation-error-install-failed-version-downgrade?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer once. It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to remove and uninstall the version on the device and then running the project. It reinstalled the version in the IDE and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Another take on the same error message: in Android Studio (unlike Eclipse), the version code/name are listed in the gradle file. If they're present both there and in the manifest, the gradle ones take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Spent an hour beating my head against the wall on this so want to share a specific quirk. Uninstalling the app via the headset didn't work - this error message still appeared, but uninstalling via sidequest and then installing the new apk worked. Good luck out there.

Answer (score 0):

Since i just had do a (split apk) downgrade again within less than a week here is how it goes, assuming you have USB debugging enabled and an **adb shell**:

1. Copy the folder with your apk's to **/data/local/tmp** since **pm** can't create an install session on **/sdcard**
2. Change to the folder and create a new install session with the total size (in bytes) of all apk's, e.g: `pm install-create -d -S 54900430‬` (mind the -d switch which isn't documented in my pm - on AOSP 12 - to enable downgrades)

   -rw-rw---- 1 shell shell **39416921** 2023-03-12 06:14 com.example.android.apk
   -rw-rw---- 1 shell shell **12141876** 2023-03-12 06:14 config.arm64_v8a.apk
   -rw-rw---- 1 shell shell   **749977** 2023-03-12 06:14 config.en.apk
   -rw-rw---- 1 shell shell  **2591656** 2023-03-12 06:14 config.xxhdpi.apk
3. Add each apk to the install session with its size and incrementing index, replace **SESSIONID** with the session id returned from **pm install-create**:

   pm install-write -S 39416921 **SESSIONID** 0 com.example.android.apk
   pm install-write -S 12141876 **SESSIONID** 1 config.arm64_v8a.apk
   pm install-write -S 749977 **SESSIONID** 2 config.en.apk
   pm install-write -S 2591656 **SESSIONID** 2 config.xxhdpi.apk
4. Finally commit the session using `pm install-commit SESSIONID`

If everything worked the shell will return **Success**

Cheers