# The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

Tags: android, installation, xiaomi

I've tried to install the application on Xiaomi Redmi 9 for the first after tring it on the emulator which worked fine but when I tried to install it on the physical device this error appeared **The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE**

Before installing a popup message said to uninstall the existing app, but I've searched on the phone everywhere but there was no app installed.

I tried to install another application on the same phone it worked fine with no error, I've no idea how to deal with this problem.

I need your help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808599/android-emulator-installation-error-install-failed-version-downgrade. Since the package name is what's used to identify the app, there may something already installed with the same package name. Try changing the package name of your app & see if it lets you install it then (instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio).

Comment: Thank you so muuch, I renamed the package and now it works fine!