# Google Play Services with Android - Not Working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, google-play-services

I'm trying to setup Google Play Services with my Android project.

While launching in device via USB debugging mode, I'm getting below error.

```
[2014-09-08 16:35:49 - google-play-services_lib] Uploading google-play-services_lib.apk onto device 'ZX1B322XZX'
[2014-09-08 16:35:49 - google-play-services_lib] Installing google-play-services_lib.apk...
[2014-09-08 16:35:50 - google-play-services_lib] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE
[2014-09-08 16:35:50 - google-play-services_lib] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-08 16:35:50 - MyApp] Launch canceled!
```

**Environment:**

```
Minimum SDK: API 8   
Target SDK: API 19

Google Play Services Version Number: 4.0.30 (889083-30)

Device OS Version: 4.4.4
Device's Google Play Services Version: 5.0.89 (1307510-034)
```

Tried with `Google Play Version: 5.0.89-000` and `Google Play Services for Fit preview`.

When trying to upgrade `Google Play Services` from Eclipse console, getting the below error:

```
[2014-09-08 16:59:52 - google-play-services_lib] Installation error! The package already exists.
[2014-09-08 16:59:52 - MyApp] Launch canceled!
```

When I press "No" while trying to upgrade `Google Play Services` from Eclipse, console displayed:

```
[2014-09-08 17:02:36 - google-play-services_lib] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2014-09-08 17:02:36 - google-play-services_lib] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2014-09-08 17:02:36 - google-play-services_lib] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.google.android.gms' in a shell.
[2014-09-08 17:02:36 - MyApp] Launch canceled!
```

Tried above method also, but nothing works..!!

**Googled and tried below approaches, but couldn't get proper solution.**

[Is there any way to ignore INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE on application install with the Android Debug Bridge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400499/is-there-any-way-to-ignore-install-failed-version-downgrade-on-application-insta)

[Android Emulator: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808599/android-emulator-installation-error-install-failed-version-downgrade)

http://androidbridge.blogspot.in/2014/05/installfailedversiondowngrade-error.html

Any Suggestions..??

**EDIT:**

*Console Log while using Emulator:*

```
[2014-09-09 10:23:58 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-09-09 10:24:19 - MyApp] ------------------------------
[2014-09-09 10:24:19 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2014-09-09 10:24:19 - MyApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-09 10:24:19 - MyApp] Performing com.hp.MyApp.SplashActivity activity launch
[2014-09-09 10:24:28 - MyApp] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-09-09 10:24:28 - MyApp] Project dependency found, installing: MyLib
[2014-09-09 10:24:30 - MyLib] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-09-09 10:24:30 - MyLib] Project dependency found, installing: google-play-services_lib
[2014-09-09 10:24:32 - google-play-services_lib] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-09-09 10:24:32 - MyLib] Project dependency found, installing: android-support-v7-appcompat
[2014-09-09 10:24:32 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Uploading android-support-v7-appcompat.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-09 10:24:33 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Installing android-support-v7-appcompat.apk...
[2014-09-09 10:24:42 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Success!
[2014-09-09 10:24:42 - MyApp] Starting activity com.hp.MyApp.SplashActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-09-09 10:24:44 - MyApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.hp.MyApp/.SplashActivity }
[2014-09-09 10:24:45 - MyApp] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.hp.MyApp' on port 8627
```

*Console Log while using USB Debugging:*

```
[2014-09-09 10:27:29 - MyApp] ------------------------------
[2014-09-09 10:27:29 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2014-09-09 10:27:29 - MyApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-09 10:27:29 - MyApp] Performing com.hp.MyApp.SplashActivity activity launch
[2014-09-09 10:27:33 - MyApp] Uploading MyApp.apk onto device 'ZX1B322XZX'
[2014-09-09 10:27:34 - MyApp] Installing MyApp.apk...
[2014-09-09 10:27:46 - MyApp] Success!
[2014-09-09 10:27:46 - MyApp] Project dependency found, installing: MyLib
[2014-09-09 10:27:46 - MyLib] Uploading MyLib.apk onto device 'ZX1B322XZX'
[2014-09-09 10:27:47 - MyLib] Installing MyLib.apk...
[2014-09-09 10:28:00 - MyLib] Success!
[2014-09-09 10:28:00 - MyLib] Project dependency found, installing: google-play-services_lib
[2014-09-09 10:28:00 - google-play-services_lib] Uploading google-play-services_lib.apk onto device 'ZX1B322XZX'
[2014-09-09 10:28:00 - google-play-services_lib] Installing google-play-services_lib.apk...
[2014-09-09 10:28:01 - google-play-services_lib] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE
[2014-09-09 10:28:01 - google-play-services_lib] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-09 10:28:01 - MyApp] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: what u r doing i mean which type of project r u doing like any new app

Comment: may be updated your goolgle play service becouse those class  u r using that not here in play Store lib

Comment: App was already developed, now I need to integrate Google Play Service.

Comment: It seems the device already has Google Play Services installed, hence the error: `[2014-09-08 16:59:52 - google-play-services_lib] Installation error! The package already exists.`, so why are you trying to install it in the first place? It doesn't really make sense ;-)